# Graph keeps updating based on the new values in the database in visual c++ via thread programming

Tags: database, winforms, visual-c++, graph

I have a database and a **winform** application in visaul c++. The db has two columns Date and Temp. These values are automatically inserted in the db by a different c++ program which is scheduled to run every 2-3 second. In the form there is a button "Show Plot" which on clicking would show the Date vs Temp graph. I am able to do this. However what i want is that this graph keeps updating based on the new values in the database...something like a heart beat monitor or to that effect. How can i achieve this. Please advice how can i do this using **winform project in visual c++ and THREAD programming**

Reards

PS: As i am using Winform application in visual c++ a lot of code is generated for th picture elemnets. Some part which may help are:

```
private: System::Void temperature_btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             String^  constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;";
             MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
             MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from `data`.`test`;",conDataBase); 
             MySqlDataReader^ myReader;

             try{
                 conDataBase->Open();
                 myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
                // MessageBox::Show("Data Inserted");
                 while(myReader->Read()){

                     String^ v_datetime;
                     String^ v_pressure;
                     v_datetime = myReader->GetString("datetime");
                     v_pressure = myReader->GetInt32("temp").ToString();

                     String^ status;
                     if (myReader->GetInt32("temp") > 1000 && myReader->GetInt32("temp") < 50 )
                     {
                         status = " Abnormal ";
                         this->chart2->Series["Temperature"]->Color = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
                     }
                     else{
                        status = " Normal";
                     }

                     this->label3->Text = status;

                     this->chart2->Series["Temperature"]->Points->AddXY(v_datetime,myReader->GetInt32("temp"));
                    // comboBox1->Items->Add(vName);

                 }
             }catch(Exception^ex){
                 MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
             }


     }
```

What needs to be done to make this dynamic...i.e, the chart keeps picking values from the database at regural intervals...say every 3-5 seconds (the db is being updated by another completely unrelated process every 2-3 second)

**PS EDIT 2: sorry...i should have made it clear... how to do this by threads...i apologise once again for not being clear**

Answer (score 1):

Add a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to your Windows Form (from the Toolbox) and register an EventHandler for the Tick event. Also set the "Intervall" to a value you want. Then either set the property "Enabled" to "true" or start it manually in the "Form_Loaded" EventHandler.

Comment: Do you still have a question? You Need to place a "Timer" on your Windows Form and then assign the property "Intervall=5000" and "Enabled=true" and double click the timer. This will lead you to the newly created Event handler and you can put this code inside the handler: `temperature_btn_Click(null, null);`

Comment: sorry...i should have made it clear... how to do this by threads...i apologise once again for not being clear

Comment: You can´t update the UI from a different thread. You can use a thread for querying the database, but then you Need to use "Invoke" or "BeginInvoke" to put the results into the "GUI-thread" so it can be displayed in the UI. You can use a Timer from the Timers Namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). The Event will be fired in a different thread.

Comment: hi..can you please ellaborate...i am not clear on those...it works by adding the timer object but the issue is that there are multiple buttons and on each button click a separate graph is displayed...so how to add timer in this cas for diiferent button clicks...that's why i was thinking of using threads